# execute jar file in command line using third party jar

Tags: java, jar, classpath

I want to execute jar in command line, but I can't solve how to add third party jar in classpath. Now the third party jar are in the current directory.

```
java -cp `pwd`/args4j-2.0.6.jar:`pwd`/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar -jar eval.jar
```

I still get the ClassNotFoundException which indicates that the JVM can't find the third party jars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something you can also try is to extract the jar and modify the `MANIFEST.MF` file to add the third party jars to `Class-Path` and zip the folder back and rename the extension to .jar.

Also you can refer the below for other ways to modify the manifest.

- http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-add-your-manifest-into-a-jar-file/
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/update.html

Answer (score 0):

you could always open cmd, and navigate to where you have the jar and execute it like you would execute a program[image: running a jar]

or add it to your env path:
system->advanced system settings->advanced->enviromental variables:
then add a ";" at the end followed by the directory where your jar is:
[image: adding env variables]

^after this you can execute it like you were before.